# How to make Android use a ZeroMQ libzmq?

Tags: android, c++, cross-compiling, zeromq

I try to port a programme from a Linux Desktop to Android. It uses `libzmq` in c++.

I want to use `zmq.hpp` (a Cpp binding of the ZeroMQ) in a native code of an App without either `jerozmq` or `jzmq`.

I ve build `libzmq` for the 4 arch with this script:

```
export PATH=/home/hmi/Android/arm-26-toolchain-clang:$PATH

rm -r /tmp/zeromq-android
cd /tmp/
#git clone https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
cd libzmq/

############################################################################
# arm-linux-androideabi
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/arm-linux-androideabi
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static                     \
            --disable-shared                     \
            --host=arm-linux-androideabi          \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"           \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
              LIBS="-lgcc"
make -j4
make install

############################################################################
# armv7a-linux-androideabi
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/armeabi-v7a
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static                     \
            --disable-shared                     \
            --host=armv7a-linux-androideabi       \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"           \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
              LIBS="-lgcc"
make -j4
make install

############################################################################   
# aarch64-linux-android
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/arm64-v8a
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static                     \
            --disable-shared                     \
            --host=aarch64-linux-android          \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"           \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
              LIBS="-lgcc"
make -j4
make install

############################################################################   
# i686-linux-android
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/x86
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static                     \
            --disable-shared                     \
            --host=i686-linux-android             \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"           \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
              LIBS="-lgcc"
make -j4
make install

############################################################################   
# x86_64-linux-android
export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/x86_64
./autogen.sh
./configure --enable-static                     \
            --disable-shared                     \
            --host=x86_64-linux-android           \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"           \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
              LIBS="-lgcc"
make -j4
make install

cd /tmp/zeromq-android/
mkdir all
cd all

for i in             \
        "armeabi-v7a" \
        "arm64-v8a"    \
        "x86"           \
        "x86_64"
     do
    mkdir ${i}
    cp -r /tmp/zeromq-android/$i/lib/* ./$i/
done





############################################################################   
## jzmq
#export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android-arm-linux-androideabi
#
#cd /tmp/
#git clone https://github.com/zeromq/jzmq.git
#cd jzmq/jzmq-jni/
#./autogen.sh
#./configure --host=arm-linux-androideabi          \
#            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR                   \
#            --with-zeromq=$OUTPUT_DIR               \
#              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include" \
#              LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib"             \
#            --disable-version                          \
#              LIBS="-lpthread -lrt"
#make
#make install}
```

Is that possible?

When linking the native-lib.cpp static and libzmq static the build is ok, but it stucks on :

> *`Runtime.error.loadingLib(native-lib)`*

When linking in native-lib shared and libzmq static the build stucks on :

> *`/home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/src/main/cpp/include/zmq.hpp:766: error: undefined reference to 'zmq_ctx_destroy'`*

I've added `libzmq` in **`CMakeList.txt`** with `add_library(zmq STATIC .../libzmq.a)`

Answer (score 0):

Given the reported error was :

> *`error: undefined reference to 'zmq_ctx_destroy'`*

it makes me believe, you may have mixed the versions.

The Git-URL leads to *"ZeroMQ core engine in C++, implements ZMTP/3.1"* for which a version 3.1, in the ZeroMQ native API, indeed does have no `zmq_ctx_destroy()` function.

You may decide, whether jump forwards, to use the [version 4.1](https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq4-1), or hack the `zmq_ctx_term()`-calls to actually call the v3.1 API present substitute `int zmq_term( void *context )`, yet proper Android-port ought live with clean API implementation, ought it not?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for replying. So for now I want to test with an Android Virtual Device(Pixel C API 28) and created a new Project with c++ Code in Android-Studio.

To get rid of `cppzmq` I use only **`libzmq`** now.
I've build **`libzmq`** with the following script :

```
#!/bin/bash

OLDPATH=$PATH

rm -r /tmp/zeromq-android
cd   /tmp/
git clone https://github.com/zeromq/libzmq.git
cd libzmq/

export NDK=$HOME/initEnvV0.0/AndroidSdk/ndk/21.0.6113669
export TOOLCHAIN=$NDK/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/linux-x86_64

# Only choose one of these, depending on your device...
#export TARGET=aarch64-linux-android
#export TARGET=armv7a-linux-androideabi
#export TARGET=i686-linux-android
export  TARGET=x86_64-linux-android

# Set this to your minSdkVersion.
export API=28

# Configure and build.
export     AR=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ar
export     AS=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-as
export     CC=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang
export    CXX=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET$API-clang++
export     LD=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ld
export RANLIB=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-ranlib
export  STRIP=$TOOLCHAIN/bin/$TARGET-strip

export OUTPUT_DIR=/tmp/zeromq-android/$TARGET
./autogen.sh
#./configure --host $TARGET
./configure --enable-static                               \
            --disable-shared                               \
            --host=$TARGET                                  \
            --prefix=$OUTPUT_DIR LDFLAGS="-L$OUTPUT_DIR/lib" \
              CPPFLAGS="-fPIC -I$OUTPUT_DIR/include"          \
              LIBS="-lgcc"                                  # ^ was missing
make
make install
```

After copying the built lib into `jniFolder`, my directory looks like this :

```
src/main/jniLibs/
└── x86_64
    ├── bin
    │   └── curve_keygen
    ├── include
    │   ├── zmq.h
    │   └── zmq_utils.h
    └── lib
        ├── libzmq.a
        ├── libzmq.la
        ├── libzmq.so
        └── pkgconfig
            └── libzmq.pc
```

I've added this to **`native-lib.cpp`**:

```
// libzmq
#include <zmq.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <assert.h>

int testlibzmq (void)
{
    //  Socket to talk to clients
    void *context = zmq_ctx_new ();
    void *responder = zmq_socket (context, ZMQ_REP);
    int rc = zmq_bind (responder, "tcp://*:5555");
    assert (rc == 0);

    char buffer [10];
    zmq_recv (responder, buffer, 10, 0);
    printf ("Received Hello\n");
    sleep (1);          //  Do some 'work'
    zmq_send (responder, "World", 5, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

My `CMakelist.txt` looks like this :

```
# For more information about using CMake with Android Studio, read the
# documentation: https://d.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html

# Sets the minimum version of CMake required to build the native library.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.4.1)

# Creates and names a library, sets it as either STATIC
# or SHARED, and provides the relative paths to its source code.
# You can define multiple libraries, and CMake builds them for you.
# Gradle automatically packages shared libraries with your APK.

include_directories(
        /home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/include
        )

add_library(           zmq STATIC     IMPORTED )
set_target_properties( zmq PROPERTIES IMPORTED_LOCATION /home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/lib/libzmq.a )
set_target_properties( zmq PROPERTIES INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES /home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/src/main/jniLibs/x86_64/include )

add_library(    native-lib                 # Sets the name of the library.
                           SHARED          # Sets the library as a shared library.
                           native-lib.cpp  # Provides a relative path to your source file(s).
                           )

# Searches for a specified prebuilt library and stores the path as a
# variable. Because CMake includes system libraries in the search path by
# default, you only need to specify the name of the public NDK library
# you want to add. CMake verifies that the library exists before
# completing its build.

find_library(     log-lib                  # Sets the name of the path variable.
                           log             # Specifies the name of the NDK library that
                           )               #           you want CMake to locate.

# Specifies libraries CMake should link to your target library. You
# can link multiple libraries, such as libraries you define in this
# build script, prebuilt third-party libraries, or system libraries.

target_link_libraries( native-lib          # Specifies the target library.
                              zmq          # Links the target library to the log library
                              ${log-lib}   #           included in the NDK.
                              )
```

Do I have to generate an `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` file next to my `jniLibs-Folder`? Did anybody try to use `libzmq` in native code without `jzmq` or `Jeromq`?

Build stucks on linking the shared `native-lib`:

```
Entering directory `/home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/.cxx/cmake/debug/x86_64'
[1/1] Linking CXX shared library /home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
FAILED: /home/hmi/barepo/AndroidCppZmq/app/build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/x86_64/libnative-lib.so
```